# jQuery.each on div in partial view always returning 1

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, asp.net-mvc

In my MVC Index page, for each element in the viewmodel, it renders via a partial view.

I then need to run a small script on each of these partial views and am trying to use `jQuery.Each()` however, i cannot seem to get it to iterate as the `$get` is always returning 1, not the actual number of elements in the `$get`.

**Index.cshtml**

```
@model IEnumerable<ViewModels.DummyVM>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "index";
}

<h2>index</h2>

<div>
    @for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
    {
        @Html.Partial("pv", i);
    }
</div>



@section Scripts
{
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            alert($("#LogEntry").length);
        })
    </script>
}
```

**PV.cshtml**

```
@model int

<div id="LogEntry">
    Log Entry : @(Model)
</div>
```

For the simplified test above, once the page has *.ready()* then iterates through  and dumps to console but I'm only getting `Log Entry : 0`

Comment: Duplicate `id` attributes are invalid html. Use a class name instead - `<div class="LogEntry">` and `$(".LogEntry")`

Comment: What happends when you replace your function with $(document).ready(function(){  alert($("#LogEntry").length);  }); ?

Comment: You should use different ids for each HTML element in your document. jQuery id selector returns the first element that has the id given to the function. [Reference](https://api.jquery.com/id-selector/)

Comment: Doh!!!..... Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`id` should be unique in same document use classes instead :

```
@model int

<div class="LogEntry">
    Log Entry : @(Model)
</div>
```

Then use class selector `.` in your JS code :

```
$(function () {
   alert($(".LogEntry").length);
})
```

If you could not edit your `PV.cshtml` page you could use :

```
$(function () {
   alert($("[id='LogEntry']").length);
})
```

Hope this helps.